# Failing to get event photo from Graph when using graph.facebook.com with event ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm using `https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/picture` to get an events photo. I've also tried attaching an access token via "access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN", but have had no luck. Here's an example:

https://graph.facebook.com/117496261723830/picture

As you can see, the graph is returning the default image ID, despite that event object [existing](https://graph.facebook.com/117496261723830). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: having same issue here @Ryan Brodie, the bug site is down.  When it is back up i will check for a bug and post back.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API does not return the event picture](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10031905/facebook-graph-api-does-not-return-the-event-picture)

Comment: here is the bug report https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/262648820496801  you can close this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users report they are able to use fql to retrieve the image: refer to http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/10364845/912623